# Unsubscribe in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the Message i am sending in mail function to unsubscribe newsletters ....

```
$this->email->message('Thanks For Subscribing ...  <a href="'.base_url().'my_admin/unsubscribe/'.$email.'">UnSubscribe</a>');
```

While Am clicking this link it will show error as

```
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

But if am not calling email ID on the link means it will work ....
So anyone suggest good solution ....
Also I want to know how to print Bootstrap elements in Mail Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "@" in file *application/config.php* in parametr "permitted_uri_chars" - it should look like that:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@';
```